# Shortcut to run the current classes main method in Eclipse? CTRL+F11 doesn't work the first time

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse used to let me run the current class with a main function in it using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> hotkey but in recent versions this seems to have changed. Now I need to run the program one time using the context menu and only from that point on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> is functional. Is there any way to get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to work the first time?

I am using Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0) on Gnome / Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Launch Operation preference on the Launching preference page. Different downloads may have changed what the default is.

https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-launching.htm?cp=1_4_4_1_1